# How to avoid this return in nested coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Here's what I want to see:

```
kango.invokeAsync('kango.storage.getItem', 'item1', function(returned1) {
    kango.invokeAsync('kango.storage.getItem', 'item2', function(returned2) {
        alert(returned1 + returned2);
    });
});
```

Here's what I wrote in coffeescript:

```
kango.invokeAsync 'kango.storage.getItem', 'item1', (returned1) ->

  kango.invokeAsync 'kango.storage.getItem', 'item2', (returned2) ->

    alert returned1 + returned2
```

The problem here is that no matter what, coffeescript is making the function ()-> return something. In that case, the last statement is being returned for some reason.

If I were to place a second alert in the nested function with returned2, it would return instead of the first one:

```
kango.invokeAsync('kango.storage.getItem', 'item1', function(returned1) {
    kango.invokeAsync('kango.storage.getItem', 'item2', function(returned2) {
      alert(returned1 + returned2);
      return alert('something');
    });
```

How to have it avoid doing the return?

Comment: Hmm, I compiled that and got what you expected.  Are you sure the indentation was as you said?

Comment: How bizarre. It seems to happen only on fiddlesalad:
http://fiddlesalad.com/coffeescript/asdfasdf-asf-asf/

Comment: I updated the question slightly.

Comment: complies for me in jsbin too. http://jsbin.com/ayejal/1/edit

Comment: Out of interest, why do you care?

Comment: The [documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#literals) is very clear that this is expected behaviour. Functions return things. They take input and yield output.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315606/coffeescript-always-returns

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want a function to return something then just say `return`:

```
kango.invokeAsync 'kango.storage.getItem', 'item1', (returned1) ->
  kango.invokeAsync 'kango.storage.getItem', 'item2', (returned2) ->
    alert returned1 + returned2
    return
```

`return` behaves the same in CoffeeScript as it does in JavaScript so you can say `return` if you don't want any particular return value.

If you don't specify an explicit return value using `return`, a CoffeeScript function will return the value of the last expression so your CoffeeScript is equivalent to:

```
kango.invokeAsync 'kango.storage.getItem', 'item1', (returned1) ->
  kango.invokeAsync 'kango.storage.getItem', 'item2', (returned2) ->
    return alert returned1 + returned2
```

The result will be the same though, `alert` doesn't return anything so:

```
f = ->
    alert 'x'
    return
x = f()
```

will give `undefined` in `x` but so will this:

```
f = -> alert 'x'
x = f()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. It seems reminiscend of def ... end of ruby, except it's return instead of end.

Answer (score 2):

In coffeescript a function always returns the final statement. You can explicitly make a function return `undefined` by making that the final statement.

```
kango.invokeAsync 'kango.storage.getItem', 'item1', (returned1) ->

  kango.invokeAsync 'kango.storage.getItem', 'item2', (returned2) ->

    alert returned1 + returned2
    `undefined`
```

Comment: or he could return returned1 + returned2 and alert them from outside

Comment: That's probably true. I think the OP may be interested in the general question of how to "not return" something though.