# coffeescript always returns

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

So I have what's probably a stupid question to ask about Coffee Script. I'm giving it a second chance but why does it return ***everything***?

Is it anything to do with being the last statement/line of the function? and how do I disable this? Putting a comment or something as the final "expression", I know it's a "documented" feature but no; no it's not really, how do I **not** have returns ***everywhere*?** and save download/execution times?

Surely this behaviour kind of screws the jit over?

```
(locate =
    getPosition: () ->
        # Check we support geolocation
        throw Exception 'Your browser doesn\'t support location based services!' if !navigator.geolocation

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (pos) ->
            console.log pos
)
```

Compiles to

```
(function() {
  var locate;

  locate = {
    getPosition: function() {
      if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        throw Exception('Your browser doesn\'t support location based services!');
      }
      return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        return console.log(pos);
      });
    }
  };

}).call(this);
```

**[Edit]**

The reason I care is this is just one of a very large library for an app I've built, if we say there's 500 functions and 200 of those do something to the dom instead of return something like a number or object, that extra 200 returns is an extra 1.2k of data I don't want or need.

Also, a function with no return, returns `undefined` and a function that returns `null` well, no need to explain that. If I was stupid enough to check this, it'd be wrong across the board.

I'm sure there would be some perf differences but I don't know about that and right now I don't have time to do some jsperfs but I'd be interested.

[image: Undefined and null]

Comment: If you don't want a value returned, end it with an empty `return` statement.

Comment: Get ready to run into a thousand other annoying things that CoffeeScript "helps" with. Good luck!

Comment: Ha, thanks for the heads up. Like I say below, I tried about 6 months ago. Binned it out because it was just awful and flakey. Giving it another chance to see why people won't quit talking about it.

Comment: @DaveMackintosh For what it's worth, I have had thousands of lines of coffeescript in production apps for almost a year now and have had nothing but amazing success using it.

Comment: @asawyer As do I, however I've not run into very many situations where CoffeeScript has sped up development.  For OP, if you start finding yourself into situations where you are debugging a lot, I'd suggest using [CoffeeCompile](https://github.com/surjikal/sublime-coffee-compile).

Comment: I'm just wondering why you care. It returns something from every function. What's the downside? A function that returns null doesn't tell you much about what happened.

Comment: I've edited with why I care

Comment: -1, shows no research effort. Yes, this is a documented part of CoffeeScript: The final statement of a method is its return value.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica As somebody who writes CoffeeScript professionally, if you are encountering "thousands" of things that annoy you, you're writing *bad* CoffeeScript. Learn to write idiomatic CoffeeScript and your relationship with the language will be dramatically improved.

Comment: @meagar Sure thing boss.

Comment: @meagar yes it's a documented feature but as the solution says it "just does it" Maybe I should have worded the question better but there should really be the option to not have this "auto-return" since it's a dreadful idea. Cheer up a bit everyone else got the question. Smile!

Comment: @DaveMackintosh It's fundamentally important to the language; you might as well ask for the ability to turn off functions or variables. As for it being a "dreadful" idea, it's one of the reasons that CoffeeScript and Ruby are wildly popular languages. If you don't get it, it's because *you don't get it* and you're not using it correctly, not because the idea itself is wrong. Spend some time writing CoffeeScript, you'll realize how wrong you are about this being a bad feature of the language.

Comment: @meagar It's a bad feature, there's no two way around it. Dreadful idea, if it was a good idea JavaScript itself would automatically add returns as the final statement of functions. The reason Coffee is popular is because it makes some peoples workflows faster, not for me. I use Node and Express a lot and it barely works in that environment (at least sensibly) so for me it's not right, don't get your knickers in a twist over my opinion of a language, I'm just one guy on the internet.

Comment: @DaveMackintosh "If it's a good feature, JavaScript would do it too" is an **incredibly** stupid argument. You could say the same for literally *every single feature* that CoffeeScript introduces. Presumably nobody would have bothered to invent CoffeeScript, if all it's features are so "dreadful" that JavaScript doesn't already do them. If you don't actually like the things that make CoffeeScript worth using, why are you trying to use it?

Comment: @DaveMackintosh I want to be perfectly clear: Because you don't understand a well-liked and popular feature of a language, you're calling it "dreadful", and a bad feature. This is utterly, utterly childish.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315606/coffeescript-always-returns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes coffeescript will always return the last line of the function.  It can do this since everything in coffeescript is an expression.

From the [docs](http://coffeescript.org/#expressions):

> #### Everything is an Expression (at least, as much as possible)
>
> You might have noticed how even though we don't add return statements to CoffeeScript functions, they nonetheless return their final value. The CoffeeScript compiler tries to make sure that all statements in the language can be used as expressions. Watch how the return gets pushed down into each possible branch of execution in the function below.

Their example can be seen [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:grade%20%3D%20(student)%20-%3E%0A%20%20if%20student.excellentWork%0A%20%20%20%20%22A%2B%22%0A%20%20else%20if%20student.okayStuff%0A%20%20%20%20if%20student.triedHard%20then%20%22B%22%20else%20%22B-%22%0A%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%22C%22%0A%0Aeldest%20%3D%20if%2024%20%3E%2021%20then%20%22Liz%22%20else%20%22Ike%22%0A%0Aalert%20eldest)

You can still do short-circuit returns with the `return` statement

> Even though functions will always return their final value, it's both possible and encouraged to return early from a function body writing out the explicit return (return value), when you know that you're done.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I thought so, how would I add my own return then? Say conditionally I want to return the geolocation inside of an `if` statement? (I wouldn't, but as an example)

Comment: you can just use `return` like normal js. If you're just starting with coffeescript, I highly reccomend reading through their website top to bottom.  It will only take about 15 minutes, and they really do a good job explaining the language.

Comment: Great, thanks! Wondered what the hoo-ha was with CoffeeScript since it seemed flaky 6 months ago. Thanks

Comment: @DaveMackintosh I rather like coffeescript, but it does have a few quirks.

Comment: @DaveMackintosh - Actually, if you want to return something directly, you don't need a `return` at all. You can just make the return value the last line of your function.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it's the last statement/line of the function, yes. By default, [functions in CoffeeScript always return a value](http://coffeescript.org/#expressions). This isn't normally a bad thing, but you can just add a `return` line if you really don't want to return anything.

If you want to return something specific, you can just make that the last line of your function:

```
(locate =
    getPosition: () ->
        # Check we support geolocation
        throw Exception 'Your browser doesn\'t support location based services!' if !navigator.geolocation

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (pos) ->
            console.log pos
            'Return this string'

        return
)
```

JS:

```
var locate;

locate = {
  getPosition: function() {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
      throw Exception('Your browser doesn\'t support location based services!');
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      console.log(pos);
      return 'Return this string';
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: A simple `return` at the end will omit the implicit return values, http://coffeescript.org/#try:f%20%3D%20()%20-%3E%0A%20%201%0A%20%20return

Comment: @asawyer - Huh, you're right. When I first tried it, it seemed to be compiling to `return return;` on the last line. I think the parser just needed a second to fix itself.